# Can I specific Per-application mappings outside of Application.cfc in CF8+?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, application.cfc

Is there a way in Adobe ColdFusion 8+ that I can change the per-application mapping  (i.e. `this.mappings`) dynamically outside of Application.cfc?

In Railo there is `<cfapplication mappings="#mappings#">`.  Any workaround for ACF?

Comment: I have to ask since I cannot come up with one on my own, but what would be a good use case for needing/wanting to do this?

Comment: the application I was working on needed 2 zones (both require Session for totally different thing), but since everything goes through index.cfm (using coldbox), I can use `<cfapplication>` in the controller with a different name, but the code that relies on mappings broke.

Comment: If you need a mapping to point to 2 different folders depending on which 'zone' they are in, why not just use different mappings for each of the 'zones'? Sorry, I still do not see your example as a good use case.

Comment: It's a little hard to explain, but yes there are work around, just not as slick as having the ability to do `<cfapplication mappings="#mappings#">` like in Railo.

Comment: If its a little hard to explain, then maybe there is an issue with the business process or work flow :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not.

Some would prefer otherwise, but we don't have the option yet.

http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/2010/02/12/applicationcfc-extends-front-controller-is-evil/ (Read in the comments)